# Representation of -1 due to bit overflow?

Tags: c, bit

Hey I was trying to figure out why `-1 << 4` (left) shift is `FFF0` after looking and reading around web I came to know that "negative" numbers have a sign bit i.e 1. So just because `"-1"` would mean extra `1` bit ie (33) bits which isn't possible that's why we consider `-1` as `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`

For instance :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("%x",-1<<4);
}
```

In this example we know that –

```
Internal representation of -1 is all 1’s 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 in an 32 bit compiler.
When we bitwise shift negative number by 4 bits to left least significant 4 bits are filled with 0’s
Format specifier %x prints specified integer value as hexadecimal format
After shifting 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 = FFFFFFF0 will be printed.
```

Source for the above 
http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-bitwise-shift-negative-number/

Comment: Left shift on negative numbers is undefined behaviour i think.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)? This is different from a simple sign bit.

Comment: @Osiris it's question from a valid question paper in the past.

Comment: @tadman Yes I am but can't see how it's applicable here..

Comment: @Osiris: Indeed it does — [C11 §6.5.7 Shift operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7): _The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 x 2E2 , reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 x 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined._

Comment: @Osiris so basically on a 32 bit it's not possible to add -1 bit so we treat (33 bit) as maximum value i.e all 1's on 32 bit

Comment: The sign bit is the first bit of the 32-bit integer, not some other 33rd bit.

Comment: Did anyone notice that the OP is programming on a 16 bit system? His compiler is most likely not even C99 compliant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, according to the C standard, the result of a left-shift on a signed variable with a negative value is undefined. So from a strict language-lawyer perspective, the answer to the question "*why does `-1 << 4` result in XYZ*" is "*because the standard does not specify what the result should be.*"

What your particular compiler is really doing, though, is left-shifting the [two's-complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of -1 as if that representation were an unsigned value. Since the 32-bit two's-complement representation of -1 is `0xFFFFFFFF` (or `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` in binary), the result of shifting left 4 bits is `0xFFFFFFF0` or `11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000`. This is the result that gets stored back in the (signed) variable, and this value is the two's-complement representation of -16. If you were to print the result as an integer (`%d`) you'd get -16.

This is what most real-world compilers will do, but do not rely on it, because the C standard does not require it.

Comment: OP reported "-1 << 4 (left) shift is FFF0" - look like a 16-bit value, not `0xFFFFFFF0 `.

Comment: @chux I doubt it, more likely sloppiness on the OP's part. Real world 16 bit machines are rare these days, and the "sample output" in the question shows 32-bit values. But even if so, it doesn't change the answer - this is correct for any platform with a standard-compliant C compiler.

Comment: 100 of millions of embedded processor per year are 16 bit theses days, not rare.

Comment: @chux I see no evidence the OP is using one of those, and again, even if they are, it does not change the validity of the answer.

Comment: The "-1 << 4 (left) shift is FFF0" is evidence, yet learners often mis-state questions.  The other UB is printing an `int` with `'%x"` that is out of `unsigned` range.  The key weakness in explaining UB comes when conveying some sort of correctness and overstating it as the behavior of "most real-world compilers" without reference.  This answer does not provide a _valid_ explanation anymore than any behavior is valid with UB.  It does provide a reasonable example of UB though.  The last line is best "do not rely on it".

Comment: @chux There is still educational value in understanding what a particular compiler is doing even in the face of UB, which is why I've included it in the answer together with very clear warnings that it is in fact UB. I don't view that as a weakness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178370/discussion-between-typeia-and-chux).

Answer (score 4):

First thing first, the tutorials use `void main`. The [`comp.lang.c` frequently asked question 11.15](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmainbooks.html) should be of interest when assessing the quality of the tutorial:

> Q: The book I've been using, *C Programing for the Compleat Idiot*, always uses `void main()`.
>
> A: Perhaps its author counts himself among the target audience. Many books unaccountably use `void main()` in examples, and assert that it's correct. They're wrong, or they're assuming that everyone writes code for systems where it happens to work.

That said, the rest of the example is ill-advised. The C standard *does not define* the behaviour of signed left shift. However, a *compiler implementation* is allowed to define behaviour for those cases that the standard leaves purposefully open. For example GCC [does define](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) that

- all signed integers have [two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format
- `<<` is well-defined on negative signed numbers and `>>` works as if by sign extension.

Hence, `-1 << 4` on **GCC** is guaranteed to result in `-16`; the bit representation of these numbers, given 32 bit `int` are `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111` and `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000` respectively.

Now, there is *another* undefined behaviour here: `%x` expects an argument that is an `unsigned int`, however you're passing in a `signed int`, with a value that is not representable in an `unsigned int`. However, the behaviour on GCC / with common libc's *most probably* is that the bytes of the signed integer are interpreted as an unsigned integer, `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000` in binary, which in hex is `FFFFFFF0`.

However, a portable C program should really **never**

- assume two's complement representation - when the representation is of importance, use `unsigned int` or even `uint32_t`
- assume that the `<<` or `>>` on negative numbers have a certain behaviour
- use `%x` with signed numbers
- write `void main`.

---

A portable (C99, C11, C17) program for the same use case, with defined behaviour, would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%" PRIx32, (uint32_t)-1 << 4);
}
```

Comment: "-1 << 4 on GCC is guaranteed to result in -16" --> Even if `int` is 2's complement, does gcc _guaranteed_   that behavior?  With gcc's many optimization abilities, I find it curious that compiler would specify that restrictive behavior, versus the potential speedier UB.

Comment: @chux see the link ;) it *is* documented.

Comment: Thanks.  I see GCC has it in [Bitwise operators act on the representation of the value including both the sign and value bits, where the sign bit is considered immediately above the highest-value value bit.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation)